# Is there anyway to add a dynamic where clause to entity to filter any query results of this entity dynamically?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, aop

I am working on an enterprise system that uses a spring boot framework and the system is stateless (no session saved).

I have `User` entity, this entity have a list of branches, and another entity called `Room`, now I need to make all rooms belong to a branch.

So, I need a generic way to add a filter on rooms to get the rooms that have matched the current user branches only (the current user who request an `API` to get some rooms and add his authorization in the request headers).

I need to make it generic to handle any request of rooms to add this filter automatically and that spare me to iterate on all old `APIs` and add this filter to on it, or an aspect to make it before any query to add a dynamic condition to it.

I tried `@Where(clause = "condition")` annotation on `Room` entity but it takes a static condition only.

Also, I tried to use `@Filter(name = "filterName", condition = "branch = :branchParam")` annotation but it need to set the parameter when a query executes, therefore in my case it won't work because I don't have one point to set this parameter to be the current user branch.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is

1. [QueryDsl](http://www.querydsl.com/)
2. [Jooq](http://www.jooq.org/)

My personal preference is QueryDsl.